# Merge PHP Array Value that have over-lapping year ranges

Tags: php, arrays, logic

If I have an array like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [last_year] => 2006
            [start_year] => 2000
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [last_year] => 2008
            [start_year] => 2001
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [last_year] => 1998
            [start_year] => 1997
        )
)
```

Is there a way I can compare the array indexes and merge `last_year` and `start_year` that are within each other? For example, the above array after being processed should be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [last_year] => 2008
            [start_year] => 2000
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [last_year] => 1998
            [start_year] => 1997
        )
)
```

Comment: what is your rule for merging?

Comment: You asked same [que](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12196910/find-total-year-spans-in-an-array-with-gaps) in different style?

Comment: same decade or same century ?

Comment: Does `[[2001, 2004], [2002, 2003], [2004, 2006]]` become `[[2001, 2006]]` or `[[2001, 2004], [2004, 2006]]`?

Comment: yes i did, but did not find a solution though :(

Comment: [[2001, 2004], [2002, 2003], [2004, 2006]] should be merged to [[2001,2006]]

Answer (score 1):

The best way I can think of is:

```
1)  sort this outer array by start_year.
2)  iterate over the outer array.
  a) If it overlaps with the next array if cur[last_year]>=next[start_year] Then
    set cur[last_year]=next[last_year]
  b) if it doesn't then cur = next and next is get next array.
```

This is NOT tested, and I haven't done PHP in a while.

```
// You can sort this array however you want, just sort by start_year.
$sortedArray = arr.sort();
$curIndx = 0;
for (int $i=1;$i<len($sortedArray);$i++){
   if ($sortedArray[$curIndx][last_year]>=$sortedArray[$i][start_year]){
      if (sortedArray[$i][last_year]>=sortedArray[$curIndex][last_year]){
          sortedArray[$curIndex][last_year] = sortedArray[$i][last_year];
      }
      unset(sortedArray[$i]);
   } else {
      $curIndx = $i;
   }
}
```

Comment: they now use dollar sign with variables in php. lol kidding. thanks mate, the sorting thing might be crazy enough to work. im ON IT!

Comment: Guh, right.  Too many languages!?! :s  I also edited it because I don't think the arrays are assigned by reference which means the arrays would be copied which means changing them doesn't change the original array.  I forget

Answer (score 0):

This is what 2AM coding produces, seems to work, though (probably not very efficient). Credit to ajon for the initial sort hint.

```
function mergeYears($data) {
    usort($data, function($a, $b) { return $a['start_year'] > $b['start_year']; });
    do {
        $hasMerges = false;
        $size = count($data);
        $merged = [];
        for($i = 0; $i < $size - 1; $i++) {
            if ($data[$i+1]['start_year'] >= $data[$i]['start_year'] && $data[$i+1]['start_year'] < $data[$i]['last_year']) {
                if ($data[$i]['last_year'] >= $data[$i+1]) {
                    $lastYear = $data[$i]['last_year'];
                } else {
                    $lastYear = $data[$i+1]['last_year'];
                }
                $merged[] = ['start_year' => $data[$i]['start_year'], 'last_year' => $lastYear];
                $hasMerges = true;
            } else {
                $merged[] = $data[$i];
            }                    
        }
        $data = ($hasMerges) ? $merged : $data;
    } while ($hasMerges);
    return $data;
}
```

http://viper-7.com/y7TJH5

Edit: Simplified code

```
function mergeYears($data) {
    usort($data, function($a, $b) { return $a['start_year'] > $b['start_year']; });
    for($i = 0; $i < count($data) - 1; $i++) {
        if ($data[$i+1]['start_year'] >= $data[$i]['start_year'] && $data[$i+1]['start_year'] < $data[$i]['last_year']) {
            $lastYearIndex = ($data[$i]['last_year'] >= $data[$i+1]['last_year']) ? $i : $i + 1;
            $merged = [
                'start_year' => $data[$i]['start_year'],
                'last_year' => $data[$lastYearIndex]['last_year']
            ];
            array_splice($data, $i, 2, [$merged]);
            $i--;
        }
    }
    return $data;
}
```

1. Sort by start_year first
2. Loop through count - 1 items
3. If the next item's start_year >= the current index's start_year and the next item's start_year is < than the current index's start_year

   - Create a merged array of the two items using the bigger last_year of the two
   - Use array_splice to remove the 2 items and replace with the merged
   - Set index back by 1 to check the new merged years with next item
4. Return the new merged year array

Comment: this line seems misplaced?
`code`
$merged[] = ['start_year' => $data[$i]['start_year'], 'last_year' => $lastYear];

Comment: If there are bugs for edges cases let me know.